# Finding the derivative containing a sum

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I'm looking into how linear regression is derived following [these steps](http://www.alfisol.com/IFS/IFS-003/DerivingLinearRegressions.php). I'm curious to how the sum is included in some terms but not others.

**Just to note, this is a question regarding finding the derivative not linear regression**

What we want to do find the minimum for the following equation.

$ε^2 = Σ (m^2x_{i}^2 + 2mbx_{i} - 2mx_{i}y_{i} + b^2 - 2by_{i} + y_{i}^2)$

So we want to find when the following two derivates in terms of m and b:

$\frac{dε^2}{dm} = 0 = 2mΣx_{i}^2 + 2bΣx_{i} - 2Σ(x_{i}y_{i})$

$\frac{dε^2}{db} = 0 = 2mΣx_{i} + 2Σb - 2Σy_{i}$

My question is when we are taking the derivative in terms of m, the term

$2mbx_{i}$ becomes $2bΣx_{i}$

but when taking the derivative in terms of b, the term

$b2$ becomes $2Σb$

What I'm failing to understand is why sum is not applied to the b term in the derivative of m but it is in the derivative of b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first one you are taking derivative w.r.t. to $m$ thus $b$ is a constant for $m$ so derivative of $2mb\sum x_i$ becomes $2b\sum x_i$

but in the second case as you mentioned you are taking derivative w.r.t. $b$

thus $m$ is treated as constant $\sum b^2$ becomes $2\sum b $

Comment: thank you for your answer! In the first instance ($2mb∑x_{i}$) why does the sum only apply to the $x_{i}$ term and not the $b$?

Comment: because you can take out b it doesn't depend on $i$   $\sum_i{} b x_i$ is same as $b \sum_{i} x_i$

Comment: $bx_1+bx_2+bx_3+....+bx_n$  is same as $b(x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n)$ right!!